# click event to show a random array element doesn't show one item

Tags: javascript

I'm newbie JS amateur. I'm trying to create a card game.
So far, I have 3 flip cards. I put them into an array. Then I wrote a function to draw a random card from the array as a button click event. (The ultimate goal is to make the card disappear after some time and let the player draw another card from the array but this will come later). I spotted one problem when I click on the button for the first time, the card appears. That's OK. When I click the button again another card appears below. But when I click for the third time on the button instead of showing the third card from the array, the second card disappears.

I thought I would add +1 to the function drawRandomCard but it's not the right thing. Can you tell me why the remaining card from the array doesn't show and help me to fix it?

```js
const card = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
const cardInner = document.querySelectorAll(".card__inner");
for (let i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
  card.item(i).addEventListener("click", function() {
    cardInner.item(i).classList.toggle("is-flipped");
  });
}

// create a card array
const arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(card);
console.log(arr);

//choose a card from the array and make it visible
function drawRandomCard() {
  arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)].classList.toggle("showMe");
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
.board {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  }
button {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  }
.card {
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  perspective: 600px;
  display: none;
  }
.card__inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  }
.card__inner.is-flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
.card__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 18px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 16px;
  }
.card__face--front {
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom right, var(--primary), var(--secondary));
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  }
.card__face--front h2 {
  color: var(--light);
  font-size: 32px;
  }
.card__face--back {
  background-color: var(--light);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  }
.btn-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: grey;
  }
.showMe {
  display: block;
  }
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <!-- ####### CARD 1 ######### -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__inner">
      <div class="card__face card__face--front">
        <h2>GAME</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="card__face card__face--back">
        <div class="card__content">
          <div class="card__header">
            <img src="" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="card__body">
            <h3>Dark Knight</h3>
            <p>Attack 12</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- ####### CARD 2######### -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__inner">
      <div class="card__face card__face--front">
        <h2>GAME</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="card__face card__face--back">
        <div class="card__content">
          <div class="card__header">
            <img src="" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="card__body">
            <h3>Unicorn</h3>
            <p>Attack 6</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- ####### CARD 3 ######### -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__inner">
      <div class="card__face card__face--front">
        <h2>GAME</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="card__face card__face--back">
        <div class="card__content">
          <div class="card__header">
            <img src="" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="card__body">
            <h3>Squirrel</h3>
            <p>Attack 1</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-container">
    <button onclick="drawRandomCard()">Pick a card</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you don't really `draw` your cards, because technically they are still in the deck (you are not removing them from the array). So if the same value comes twice for `Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)` you call `toggle("showMe")` again and by doing so you are removing the class `showMe` from that element

(EDIT: See @Bao Huynh Lam example for better understanding)

Anyway... One easy fix is removing the drawed card from the array. So something like:

```
//choose a card from the array and make it visible
function drawRandomCard() {
  if(!arr.length) return;
  const cardDrawedIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  arr[cardDrawedIndex].classList.toggle("showMe");
  arr.splice(cardDrawedIndex, 1);
}
```

Or if you need the old array you could just create a variable (ex availableCards) and use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) when the function is entered to save the cards which doesn't have the `showMe` class.

---

**Edit: if you need to remove the elements from the doom and appending them 1 by 1**:

1. Add `id="board"` to your `<div class="board">` container (you can also use the class for this but it would be safer and a better practice to use id.
2. After you get the elements *(with `const card = document.querySelectorAll(".card");` and
   `const cardInner = document.querySelectorAll(".card__inner");`)*, empty the container ( if you added the id use `document.getElementById("board").innerHTML = "";`)
3. After you toggle the class append the element to the container (

   `arr[cardDrawedIndex].classList.toggle("showMe");` +
   `document.getElementById("board").append(arr[cardDrawedIndex])`

)

You can also get rid of `display: none` from `.card` with this approach and get rid of `.showMe` class as well as `arr[cardDrawedIndex].classList.toggle("showMe");` line.

Comment: Thanks that solves one problem. Three cards are shown but they are not random. They are always the same. They are not RANDOM.

Comment: The order they are drawn is random. If you hide the old one when you draw the new one it will be like the user draws a random card. But if you really want the cards to be represented in random order in the DOM you need to add them dynamically  to it. So store the value in a string and use `.append` to add them to the container: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append .

Comment: That's usually the point when I really want to quit JS :) The further you go into the forest, the more trees. I need to take a break. But thanks for your time.

Comment: Another way that might suit you better would be to get all elements from doom, empty the dom via js and then append just one of them at a time, and constantly emptying the container. I will make a quick edit explaining the steps

Comment: Done. PS: for removing the card when a new one is drawn you can just empty the container again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is RANDOM picking. Your `drawRandomCard` function bears the responsivity of 1. Picking a random card and 2. **Toggle** the "showMe" class.

However, since you are having no way to make sure the new random card DOES NOT equal old cards, what happened was that:

1. Draw random --> Card 1 --> Toggle "show me" --> Card 1 now has "showMe"
2. Draw random --> Card 2 --> Toggle "show me" --> Card 2 now has "showMe"
3. Draw random --> Card 2 --> Toggle "show me" --> Card 2 stops having "showMe"

This is a random process, so it can go 1 2 2 but also 1 2 3 or 3 3 3. You can't really know for sure which next card will be accidentally toggled on or off.

One (albeit inefficient if the deck is large) way to fix this is to add some logic to keep re-rolling until the picked card DOES NOT have "showMe" already.

```js
function drawRandomCard() {
  newCard = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
  while (newCard.classList.includes("showMe")) {
     // Reroll until the new card classList does not contain "showMe"
     newCard = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]
  }
  newCard.classList.toggle("showMe");
}
```

Comment: While your fix works, for a real deck (52 cards) it would be very inefficient to draw the last card(s) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
```

if arr.length = 3, above will return a random number between 0 and 2
So when you click the button 3 times, you could get 0 1 2
Next time you do it 0 1 1, and so on randomly
So it could easily repeat a number in a cycle.
So while you see the 3 cards appearing correctly sometimes, other times you will get repeating cards.

Answer (score 0):

Put it simply, your code picks a random card from the deck to toggle the showMe class.

What's happening is that sometimes you randomly pick a card that already has this class applied so you end up removing the class and hiding it.

There are multiple ways to go about fixing this bug, one way is that:

Rather than picking any random card and toggling showMe. You could edit your drawRandomCard() business logic so that it:

1. Draws a random card
2. Checks to see if the showMe class has been toggled already, if not draw another random card until you do so and only then
3. toggle the showMe class on the randomly drawn card

You could also keep a list of cards you have drawn and check if you've already drawn that card before applying the toggle.